# JavaScript callback function not recognising namespace properties or functions

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript and was really getting along well with it until a few hours ago and this has got me stumped.

My question is with the callback which i don't think i'm doing right. Essentially, on the `Init` of the `App.Map` which is called from the `html` page, the script will load the google maps script and execute the code in the callback. This all works fine. The problem is when i'm stepping through the script in the `load` function, the `location` should be `null` but isn't. However, if i use `App.Map.location` in place of `location` the variable is correct and equal to `null`.

Secondly, the commented out line `ClearMarkers();` throws an error that it is not recognised when i step through the script.

I'm not doing something right, what would be the correct way to implement a callback this way?

Namespaces:

```
var App = App || {};
App.Map = App.Map || {};
```

App namespace:

```
(function(ns) {

    ns.LoadScript = function(url, callback) {

        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';

        if (script.readyState) {
            script.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (script.readyState === 'loaded' ||
                    script.readyState === 'complete') {

                    script.onreadystatechange = null;
                    callback();
                }
            };
        } else {
            script.onload = function() {
                callback();
            }
        }

        script.src = url;
        document.head.appendChild(script);
    };

})(App);
```

Map namespace:

```
(function(ns) {

    ns.position = {
        lat: -34.397,
        lng: 150.644
    };
    ns.location = null;

    var key = '';
    var map;
    var markers = [];

    ns.ClearMarkers = function () {
        if (markers.length !== 0) {
            markers.forEach(function (marker) {
                marker.setMap(null);
            });
            markers = [];
        }
    };

    var load = function () {

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: this.position
        });

        //ClearMarkers();

        if (location) {
            alert("perform search with this location");
        } else {
            alert("find current location");                
        }
    };

    ns.Init = function (data, options) {

        this.location = data && data.location ? data.location : null;

        App.LoadScript('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=' + key + '&libraries=places', load);
    };

})(App.Map);
```

Thanks for any help and if the question needs reworking please let me know.

Comment: the way you wrote it, `location` references `window.location`, not `ns.location`. Take a look into variable scopes, closures and the quirks of `this` in JS. `this.position` will also fail in this code, because `this` ain't what you think in that context.

Comment: no, it's because you have not declared any variable by that name anywhere in your code, so it tries to find one in the surrounding scopes, and it finally finds one on window, the global scope. As said, read up the mentioned topics, pretty much everything that has to do with how variables and `this` work in JS. These topics have been explained and discussed way too often to do that again.

Comment: Your second issue about `ClearMarkers()` being undefined is because it exists as a property of `ns` so you would want to access it as `ns.ClearMarkers()`

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, i've managed to get it working now. I'm looking at some material on pluralsight regarding scopes, closure and this in javascript. I'm from a c# background and although there are some similarities it's a little confusing.